# Can't find newer DLINK Router DIR-400 firmware

Tags: wireless-router, firmware

If you're here, it means you also have a Dlink 400 router.

I asked DLINK but they didn't answer my question. I asked DLINK support again, but this time no answer (2 weeks later).

In [DLINK FTP site](ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Gateway/) there is no firmware for DIR-400.

Past year, Googling around Russia, I found a [FIRMWARE_DIR400_v1.02B03.bin](http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Router/DIR-400/Firmware/).

But I am trying to figure out if is there **any update**, a 1.03 version or superior.

Can anyone tell me why DLINK doesn't show this firmware update on their site, and if this DIR-450 is compatible with mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the newest driver 1.03 (2009 year)

http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Router/DIR-400/Firmware/release_note.txt

Funny, I can't find it on USA site and Latin America sites.

Comment: actually is a change log, you could go to ttp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Router/DIR-400/Firmware or get it here http://www.4shared.com/file/084xQy4g/firmware_DLINK_DIR400_A1_FW103.html

Comment: a newer link: http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, companies will remove links to software if that software was defective or buggy. In other cases, companies seem to pay little attention to how well they keep their support sites up to date. Hard to tell without an answer from them.

The short answer is no, that firmware wouldn't work for you. It is very possible that it would, but any incompatibilities may brick your router, so you don't want to try that.

On the other hand, you could always try custom firmware, such as the highly rated [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware, which supports your router.

Comment: the new firmware is working, but the main problem in all versions is some sort of intermittent bug: sometimes wireless connection stops working and I have to connect directly my notebook to modem :(

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're looking for a newer firmware?

I've flashed mine with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) and never looked back since then. It adds so much more functionality and flexibility to your router.

Comment: I was trying to see if a new firmware would fix this wireless disconnection problem between my notebook and DLINK DIR-400